# If the Covariance between $(X,Y)$ is finite, then the second moment of $X$ is finite?

Tags: probability, covariance

> If the Covariance between $(X,Y)$ is finite, then the second moment of $X$ is finite.

I think that this statement is false, but I can´t find a counterexample....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy counterexample is to take $Y$ to be a constant random variable. Then the covariance between $X$ and $Y$ is zero:
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=E(cX)-E(X)E(c)=cE(X)-cE(X)=0,
$$
even if $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\infty$.

Comment: But to give a concrete counterexample it is necessary that $E(X)$ exists right? Because I read the answer of Jeremy but, we have something like $0(\infty)$ for $E(X)E(Y)$ right? Well. I know that the covariance between a constant and a random variable is 0 but I don't remember if it's necessary the existence of the first moment of the random variable

Comment: @EduardoCuéllar Yeah, you want an example where covariance can be calculated, which requires $E(X)$ to exist in the first place. So a counterexample is any random variable $X$ for which $E(X)$ exists but $E(X^2)=\infty$; then let $Y$ have constant value $c$.

Comment: I just found a random variable with those properties. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Let $X, Y$ be random variables such that

$$X = \begin{cases} 1.9^i, & i = 1, 2, 3, ... \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} \\ P(X = i) = \begin{cases} (\frac 12)^i, & i = 1, 2, 3, ... \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} \\ Y = 0 \ \text{ with probability }\ 1.$$

$$\mathsf{E}[X^2] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty 1.805^i = \infty, \mathsf{E}[XY] = \mathsf{E}[0] = 0$$

Therefore the statement is untrue.

Comment: I see that $E\[XY\]=0$ but $E\[Y\]E\[X\] $ wouldn't be an indetermination of the type $0(\infty)$ then the covariance doesn't exist?

Comment: @EduardoCuéllar Good point. I edited it so that it works (I think).